# Minimum Uncertainty Wavepackets

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I'm reading over some lecture notes on minimum uncertainty wavepackets in quantum mechanics, and I've come across a statement that I'm not entirely convinced by.
My take on minimum uncertainty states are that they are the most particle-like states which exist in a given Schrödinger system. In the harmonic oscillator, the minimum uncertainty state is like a circle of quantum noise which follows the classical path in phase space, and if you take the limit as $\hbar \rightarrow 0$, it reproduces exactly the classical behaviour.

But in the lecture notes I'm reading, it states that:
"Decreasing $\Delta x$ and increasing $\Delta p$ gives a more wave-like state, and increasing $\Delta x$ and decreasing $\Delta p$ gives a more  particle-like state"
(And I assume that this is referring to keeping $\Delta x \Delta p = \hbar/2$)

I agree with the first statement; as we increase uncertainty in $x$ and decrease uncertainty in $p$ we get more like a classical wave, where there is no well-defined x-position that's any more characteristic of the wave than any other, but the wave has a well-defined velocity.
I'm not happy with the second statement though. In classical mechanics we have $\Delta x = \Delta p = 0$, so we know an equal amount of information about the two variables. To me this means that if we take a state with equally minimised uncertainty between $x$ and $p$, we again know the same amount of information about the two variables, and this state is the state most like the classical system. If we then increase uncertainty in momentum and decrease uncertainty in position, we move away from what was our most particle-like state.

It seems to me that if we make $\Delta p > \Delta x$, this is still like a wave, it's just that the wave is now distrubuted in such a way in phase space that it doesn't resemble our normal idea of a classical wave (or indeed anything at all).

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: There's no real physics question here, but I'll say that the statement in the lecture notes is imprecise and cavalier.  What is "more wave like" and "more particle like"?  The author is opening a can of worms that can lead nowhere constructive.

Comment: One may dial a "squeezing parameter" moving uncertainty from *x* to *p* in phase space, all the while preserving a minimal product for (nondispersive) coherent states, but the intuition involved designating a particle as something well-defined in space but not in momentum is kind of flakey, even though particle physics experiments do rely in this type of classical intuition....